# Bootstrap hamburger menu when menu contains too many menu items

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap has this feature of collapsing menu items in the [`navbar`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) to a hamburger menu when certain window size breakpoints are reached. However, I sometimes find that even on bigger size screens that wouldn't trigger this responsive hamburger button behaviour (because they are well beyond the breakpoint), the hamburger button should appear when the navbar gets too full (i.e. when there are too many menu items).

Is there a way to accomplish this, preferably built-in, or with css/html only or minimal JS effort? Has anyone tried this before and can share code and experiences?

Comment: what did you try so far? if you look at the documentation you posted, it says: `.collapse.navbar-collapse` «for grouping and hiding navbar contents by a parent breakpoint» and «Add an optional `.navbar-scroll` to set a `max-height` and scroll expanded navbar content» did you try those options?

Comment: it would be nice to have more information, but I don't think the ``.navbar-scroll`` applies because they are referencing when the width gets too full, not height? I usually use this page for examples for navbars: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/navbars/

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: I will suggest that a menu that's too full just needs fewer items. It's a usability faux pas. Consider restructuring to reduce clutter.

Comment: @GrafiCode `navbar-scroll` is for vertical scrolling when the hamburger dropdown appears and `.collapse.navbar-collapse` enables this behaviour (which is what I am using, but it depends on the window width rather than the number of items in the dropdown).

Comment: @BrandonTrecki nice link - I could use the "Expand at lg" option which would alleviate the problem somewhat...

Comment: @isherwood in which way do you think my question can be improved.

Comment: @isherwood agree - but it's user definable, so I don't have much control over that (neither length of menu item strings, nor number of items).

Comment: Did you read that page? You're expected to show some code demonstrating the problem or situation. We don't do hypotheticals here.

Comment: Did you read my post? There's a link that points to numerous examples on the Bootstrap page (those are the ones that I am referring to).

Answer (score 1):

So I am somewhat shooting in the dark on this answer but I think I understand. The Bootstrap Docs provide examples and the Navbar example is a good resource to see the flexibility and responsive classes that are available.

- [Bootstrap 4.6 Navbar Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/navbars/)
- [Bootstrap 5.0 Navbar Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbars/)

Aside from the `.navbar-expand-lg` classes, Bootstrap doesn't have the native functionality to know when to collapse or not.

Maybe these JavaScript solutions that I have may inspire.

- [Carousel style horizontal navbar](https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/dyJjNEP)
- [jQuery Custom scrollbar plugin: Demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollTo_demo.html)

Comment: I like the carousel option - I hadn't seen this before.

Comment: yeah its pretty slick, JS is intermediate level maybe. Also I saw your link was for BS 5.0 so I added the navbar example for BS 5.0. Mine was for BS 4.6. Theres a lot of helpful stuff in the examples section